# How to test multiple conditions using not equal?

Tags: javascript

My code is not working.

I am trying to test if my variable is not equal to any of my conditions.

```
function text(){
    if( input!="BSIT" || input!= "BSBA"|| input!="BSN") { .. }
}
```

Comment: If you want to check if it equals NONE of the values, then you need to use AND logic (i.e. &&), not OR

Comment: also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also, you do realize that Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `||` should be `&&`s.

You want to test if *all* the conditions are true, not if *any* of them are true. `||` will return true as soon as at least one is true.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java